# How to start a node js server when Autoscalling a EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, autoscaling

I have a EC2 instance which runs node js Servers but when autoscalling I want the newly generated instance to run the node Server  .What can I do to make sure instances run the node server on boot

I have tried to use forever but I am not sure how to use it.Is there any way i can use cronjob to do this
As of now i installed npm install forever -g 
and installed forever-monitor in my directory where Server.js is running

```
  const http = require('http');

const app = require('./app');

var accesslog = require('access-log');

const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;



const server = http.createServer(app);




server.listen(port);
```

Comment: How are you using "forever"? It should work. Please update your question with some piece of code so people can help.

Answer (score 1):

Create an AMI that has your script as a service, by following this guide
https://timleland.com/how-to-run-a-linux-program-on-startup/

Then just have your Autoscale group launches instances with that AMI

Comment: so if my  Server.js file is in home/ubuntu/backend/Server.js my EXECSTART should be home/ubuntu/backend/node Server.js?